# jquery create html add javascript event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created html using jquery and added a javascript event command in tag html. Compile is invalid

ex.

```
var text = 'abc';
var id = 1;
html = "<tr onclick='test("+id +", '"+text +"');'></tr>";
```

Compile

```
<tr onclick="test(1, " abc');'=""></tr>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: onclick function not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your second single quote is closing the onclick value, replace the single quotes around text with escaped double quotes.
Try replacing this line

```
html = "<tr onclick='test("+id +", \""+text +"\");'></tr>";
```

Or since attribute values will end up with double quotes anyway,

```
html = '<tr onclick="test('+id +', \''+text +'\');"></tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like the following way:

```js
var text = 'abc';
var id = 1;
var html = `<tr onclick="test(${id},'${text}')"><td>Sample Data</td></tr>`;
document.querySelector('table tbody').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

function test(elId, elText){
  console.log(elId + '::' + elText);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

create element and add event using jquery

```js
var text = 'abc';
var id = 1;

html = $('<tr><td>click Me!</td></tr>').click(function() {
  test(id, text);
})

$('table').append(html);

function test(id, txt) {
  console.log(id, txt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```